# Python 3: How to solve this problem: ImportError: lxml not found, please install it?

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, importerror, python-3.8

I have written following code in Pycharm (macOS):

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.wolfspeed.com/products/power/sic-mosfets/'

tables = pd.read_html(url)

print(tables)
```

And I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    tables = pd.read_html(url)
  File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 1212, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 977, in _parse
    parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
  File "/Users/wenjiehe/PycharmProjects/Half-Bridge_SiC/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 934, in _parser_dispatch
    raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it
```

I have already done this:
1）`pip3 install lxml` in Terminal, but still got this error after restarting the Pycharm.
2） uninstall pandas and lxml and install them again, still didn't work.
3) `conda install -c anaconda lxml`, it took about 30 mins but also didn't work.
4) upgrade lxml and pandas
All the attempts above failed.

I also check the Python Interpreter:
[python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKnQx.png)

Why did this error keep showing up? Are there any other approaches?

Comment: It could be that you installed lxml on a wrong python environment. Check the name of the python interpreter that you are using in Pycharm and make sure to install lxml on that specific interpreter.

Comment: If it is taking so long for conda to resolve your environment, it **may** also well be that you have been fiddling with this env for a long time and that it starts to be quite bloated. It often happends (to me at least) that you need to create a new fresh environment with the packages that you realy need, letting the dependencies being solved, rather than trying to fix manually an environment with lots of packages already contraining other packages versions, that tends to conflict between each others. Often it is much easier this way.

Comment: Thanks Ted, I've checked the python interpreter in PyCharm preferences and lxml is inside the list, maybe i should find another way

Comment: Thank you Osamoele for your advice, it does sound reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

### You can check the packages which are installed by opening the setting in PyCharm

- Setting >> Project >> Python Interpreter
- Check if lxml is inside the list.
- If not, you can also install by pressing the "add" button

Hope This can fix or solve your problem !

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I checked the python interpreter and lxml is inside the list...

Answer (score 0):

### **Change Python Interpreter to Conda Environment**

I've solved this problem by changing the Python interpreter from Python 3.8 to Conda Environment Python 3.8.

[python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMfqZ.png)

Specific steps:
Click PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project -> Python Interpreter -> Click the setting button -> Add, and then change the environment.

Hope this can help someone who is also struggling with this problem.